# How can I connect to k3d kubernetes running on my host to Jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, k3s, k3d

I am running a Jenkins docker container, which I want to configure the Kubernetes plugin which requires passing kubeconfig file. How can I point the kubeconfig file in my local machine to the Jenkins running in the container? I am running the k3d Kubernetes cluster on my host machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can **mount** the host directory to the container.

So your host directory will be accessible inside the **Jenkins** container and you can access the files also.

This way just mount your `.kube` folder to Jenkins container, which is storing the `kubeconfig` file. And you can use that path in jenkin config.

Create a home directory for Jenkins in the host.

```
 sudo mkdir /mykubeconfig
```

copy-paste the `kubeconfig` file inside above created directory

Run the latest Jenkins container using the following command.

```
 docker run  -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /mykubeconfig:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Now you will be able to access jenkins on host port 8080.